# Android: ActivityNotFound Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Basically the error is in Manifest file I think.

Here is the code for MainActivity.java

```
private void setInitialScreen( int visibility ) {
    Button choose_picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_picture);
    choose_picture.setVisibility(visibility);
    choose_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.addCategory("choose_file");
            Log.d("mainactivity", intent.getCategories().toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(data.hasCategory("choose_file") && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        setPhotoEditScreen(0, uri);
    }
}

private void setPhotoEditScreen( int visibility, Uri uri ) {
    View screen_image_editing = findViewById(R.id.screen_image_editing);
    screen_image_editing.setVisibility(visibility);
    ImageView main_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
    main_image.setImageURI(uri);
}
```

and this is the manifest entry

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="choose_file"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Screenshot of Logcat

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0hi3g7n3i966t6/Screenshot%202014-04-14%2010.33.17.jpg

Comment: can u show ur log report??

Answer (score 1):

```
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="choose_file"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Please do remove the following lines from manifest.xml and try it out , I think since it has two intent filters there might be a problem and in the android name and have you included the package name in the

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.splash_1"
```

Like this

Comment: I don't think this will be a problem, but how else I would achieve that? I mean intent filter will be searched in Manifest file. Right?